# use .env file in hosting on netlify

Tags: github, rapidapi, .env

i am using my github repository to constant update a site i made using shazam core api, the api key is stored in an env file(locally) which is safe but is not uploaded on github due to .gitignore security.but the hosting will not work without the api key.
the enviroment variable are too giving error!

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 ()
"message":"Invalid API key. Go to https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/keys for more info."}

thanks.

trying to find a way to use my env file on github without exposing it

Answer (score 0):

You can use their CLI's [`env:import` command](https://cli.netlify.com/commands/env/#envimport)

```
netlify env:import .env
```

Or, you can set your environment variables from your website's settings, on this page:

[image]

Read more at:

- https://docs.netlify.com/environment-variables/overview/
- https://cli.netlify.com/